# ajax can't send the request to another php page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

my php page use ajax to send a request to the other page, but somehow the request seems cannot be sent, I have test update_ok.php and should be ok with those code, I think the problem is from sending the request by the ajax. the code as following, please help me out bro.

update.php

```
<?php
<table>  
<tr class="item">
<form action="" method="POST" name="form" id="form">
<input name="id" type="hidden" class="normalinput" id="id" value="<?php echo $row_result2["id"];?>">
<input name="gp_name" type="hidden" class="normalinput" id="gp_name" value="<?php echo $row_result2["gp_name"];?>">
<input name="city" type="text" class="normalinput" id="city" size="6" value="<?php echo $row_result2["city"];?>"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="arrange" type="text" class="normalinput" id="arrange" size="10" value="<?php echo $row_result2["arrange"];?>"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="qua" type="text" class="normalinput" id="qua" size="1" value="<?php echo $row_result2["qua"];?>"></td>
<td align="center">
<input name="id" type="hidden" class="normalinput" id="id" value="<?php echo $row_result2["id"];?>">
<input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="update">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Update" onClick="update(form);"></td>

<td align="center">
<input name="id" type="hidden" class="normalinput" id="id"  value="<?php echo $row_result2["id"];?>">
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Delete" onClick="window.location.href='delete.php?id=<?php echo $row_result2['id'];?>'" />
</td>
</form>
</tr><?php }?>
</table>
```

index.js

```
function update(form){
var xml;
if(window.ActiveXObject){
    xml=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}else if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xml=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
var id=form.id.value;
var city=form.city.value;
var gp_name=form.gp_name.value;
var arrange=form.arrange.value;
var qua=form.qua.value;

xml.open("GET","update_ok.php?id="+id+"&city="+city+"&gp_name="+gp_game+"&arrange="+arrange+"&qua="+qua,true);
xml.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xml.readyState==4&&xml.status==200){
        var msg=xml.responseText;
        if(msg==1){
            alert("Update succeed!!");
            location.href='index.php';
        }else{
            alert("Update False");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
xml.send(null);
}
```

update_ok.php

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
include_once("conn/connMysql.php");

$id=$_GET['id'];
$gp_name=$_GET['gp_game'];
$arrange=$_GET['arrange'];
$city=$_GET['city'];
$qua=$_GET['qua'];
$sql=mysql_query("update gp_info set gp_name = '$gp_name', city = '$city', qua = '$qua', arrange = '$arrange' where id=".$id);
if($sql){
$reback=1;
}else{
$reback=0;
}
echo $reback;
?>
```

Comment: `<form>` is not a valid child of `<tr>`. Try wrapping it around the table instead

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Network tab. Press the Update button and you'll see your ajax request and your php page's response. Do you see what you expect?

Comment: Thanks, I find out some var was wrong and I correct it. now I got "Update False" message, I am not familiar with JS, do you know if index.js is correct or not? I already correct "&gp_name="+gp_game to "&gp_name="+gp_name.